# How do you italicize a word in a text field an have it output in italics to a text area?

Tags: java, text, output

In my program, I have an add button and add button to add the whole citation to an array.

```
    String citeString;
    citeString = "";

    citeString = lastNameInput.getText()+", "+firstNameInput.getText()+",``"+titleInput.getText()+", "+EditionInput.getText()+", "+PublisherInput.getText()+", "+placePublicationInput.getText()+", "+yearPublicationInput.getText()+".";

    Collections.addAll(Citation,citeString);
    Collections.sort(Citation, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

I also have a display button to display the citation to text field

```
String outString = "";

   Collections.sort(Citation, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   for(int e=0;e<Citation.size();e++){
       outString = outString+Citation.get(e)+"\n";
   }
   citeOutput.setText(outString);
```

I need to italicize the titleInput. How do I do that?

Comment: i forgot to mention this is in java sorry

Comment: You could edit the question and update tags there...

Comment: Are you outputing to a Swing app, or what?

Comment: Yes I am using a Swing app